# Back function with remove array

Tags: android, arrays, actionscript-3, flash

i'm using Flash cs6 as3 with air creating a simple android app is all about 3 scenes 
scene 1 is the menu scene
scene 2 is for a type of images using array (pictureArray[m])
scene 3 is for another type of images also using array ((pictureArray2[n])

so when press back button on the device , it should bring me back to scene 1 (menu scene)

so when back from scene 2 to scene 1 the picture array removes well 
but when back from scene 3 to scene 1 , it back successfully, but the image in the pictureArray2 stays at the background :(

what shall I do so that I can back to the main scene with removing all arrays !!

this is the back code i'm using at scene 1

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, CheckKeypress, false, 0, true)

function CheckKeypress(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
    switch (event.keyCode) 
    { 
        case Keyboard.BACK: 
        event.preventDefault();
        gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 1");
             removeChild(pictureArray[m]);
         removeChild(pictureArray2[n]);

        } 
        }
```

Comment: Can we see a picture (screen shot) of your timeline?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the timeline or knowing where m and n come from.

if it is OK to remove all members of pictureArray and pictureArray from the stage when you switch scenes, try adding this function and calling it before you go from one scene to another:

```
function removeParents(myArray:Array) : void{
    for each(var object:DisplayObject in myArray)
    {
        if(object.parent)
        {
            object.parent.removeChild(object);
        }
    }
}
```

so use it like this:

```
...
removeParents(pictureArray);
removeParents(pictureArray2);
gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 1");
....
```